# Using localization from server in Swift 5 app

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, localization, swift5

For certain reasons, I've implemented a webview in a native ios app, and I want to avoid having to update the app more than necessary. For this reason, I don't want to use native localization but instead get the translation files from the webpage. I set up the bridge between the webview and the app and takes a json that I converts successfully to a [String: String] to use in the app.

The crux is that the user can change language, which will send a new dictionary to the app. For this reason, I'm using the [String: String] dictionary as an environment element.

I'm having trouble setting this up in a non-intrusive way, meaning I want the code to be as invisible as possible in the views. I'm just learning SwiftUI, jumping from Swift 3, and been reading up on this for two days.

---

1. Is there a certain native localization implementation for this that I have overseen, other than using a bundle?
2. I don't want to create new Custom Views, like LocalizedText instead of just Text.
3. I'm using a key to do a lookup in the [String: String] dictionary.
4. I want the implementation of the localization to as invisible as possible in all views.

---

```
   Text(localized: "greetings")  // Displays "Hello world!"
```

... is OK, but I would prefer:

```
   Text("greetings")            // Displays "Hello world!"
```

---

5. Would it be possible to create a more general implementation of the extension I've made, or do I have to do an extension for every type of View that takes a string as an argument, like Buttons and TextFields?

Working existing code below, which is OK, but I think it looks weird to send in the key in a modifier.

What I'm asking is basically: is there a better way of achieving automatic updates of locale from a server (webpage, in this case) with less intrusive code in the views?

```
// Example of an implementation of the existing localization
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
            Text("")
                .localized("Greetings")     // Outputs "Hello world!"
  }
}


// Setting up environment object
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    
      var dictionary = DictionaryViewModel()

      let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(dictionary)

      // No magic here; same as usual
      if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
          let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
          window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
          self.window = window
          window.makeKeyAndVisible()
      }
   }
   
   /../
}

// Called from the webview via dictionaryViewModel.send([String: String]) after the webpage has loaded.
final class DictionaryViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var list = [String: String]()  // ex. {"greetings": "Hello world"}
}

// Wraps a Modifier()
extension Text {
    func localized(_ key: String) -> some View {
        modifier(Localized(key: key))
    }
}

struct Localized: ViewModifier {
    @EnvironmentObject var dictionary: DictionaryViewModel
    
    let key: String
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if let translation = dictionary.list[key.lowercased()] {
            return Text(translation)
        }
        
        return Text(key)
    }
}
```

---

### [edit] Follow up

I had some graphical errors running this code, where certain Text blocks were almost or fully transparent. I discovered that I needed to restart XCode and its simulator to make the bug disappear.

Some more googling made me find [Dynamic Localization in iOS](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/localisation-in-ios-e88ef27b6faa), where you can use `manager.createFile` to store the dictionary, and then use the built in bundle parameter. I went with my solution anyway, because it made as much hassle as that solution.

Comment: How often will these localized strings be changed? Moving them in the cloud makes things so much more complicated that it must be special texts that change every few days on and on and on.

Comment: The app won't be worked on continuously, otherwise I would agree with you. There are other benefits in using cloud translations - one that non-developers can update the language strings. In this company, that one have been a bliss for us developers.

Comment: Although this is not a full solution on its own, I can recommend `attranslate` to convert JSON-files into iOS-strings: https://github.com/fkirc/attranslate